# Developing behave steps with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev, bdd

[Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/) is a great tool for behavior driven development in Python. However, in combination with PyDev I've got two Problems:

1. PyDev can't resolve behave's `@given`, `@when` and `@then` annotations. This probably happens because behave does some name magic the `behave` package.
2. behave suggests to name all methods `step` as every method has an annotation which defines the "real" name. PyDev complains about these "duplicate" methods.

   Example:

   ```
   from behave import given, when, then

   @given('I navigate to Google')
   def step(context):
       # ...

   @when('I enter coffee into the search field')
   def step(context):
       # ...
   ```

By now, I work around both Problems by including `#@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore`, which turns off any PyDev analysis. I'd like to keep PyDev analysis for all other parts of the code.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just a guess. Have You tried with import redefinitions?

   ```
   from behave import given as given_behaviour, when as when_behaviour, then as then_behaviour
   @given_behaviour('I navigate to Google')
   ```

   You can also check the eclipse settings: menu Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreters. Sometimes it might help to remove and re-add the python interpreter if new libraries has been added after that the interpreter was configured in order to include those in the System `PYTHONPATH` in eclipse.
2. Try adding `#@` followed by the message in camel case to the end of the method name to turn off the warning message in PyDev. Something like:

   ```
   def step(context): #@DuplicatedSignature
   ```

Comment: i tried above solutions and it didn't work. Any other pointers?